# Iterating through an array and highlighting row where data is [Google Sheet script]

Tags: javascript, google-docs

Looking for someone to help troubleshoot my script.

I'm trying to write a script that requests an input from the user, iterates through a dataset searching for the input and will highlight all cells in the corresponding row red.

I appreciate this is a fairly basic request but having browsed Stackoverflow/the wider web for several hours and implementing solutions to different problems to no avail, can someone please help me fix my code.

example:

Given this sample data. If the user input "C" then all cells in row 3 (C, 5, 8) would be highlighted red

1. A 3 6
2. B 5 8
3. C 5 8
4. D 8 4

We want the user to input "C" and all corresponding active cells for row 3 to have their background changed to red.

Any help is much appreciated.

```html
function HighlightMyTablet() {
  // Scan data in sheet. 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var row = ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  // Prompt user for input. 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('What\'s the tablet of the month?', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  
  // Iterate through rows. If data matches input then highlight yellow.
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    for (i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
      if(values[i][0] == response) {
        values[i][0].setBackground("red");
      }
    }  
  } 
}
```

Comment: first of all take note that if the user inputes a lowercase character it won't match anything i.e if the response variable holdes a lowercase character "c" the `if` statement will fail

Comment: @VictoryOsikwemhe Thank you for the feedback. I will incorporate a match function instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with what the commenter said, you need to make sure that you actually want === and not a `.match(new RegExp(user_input, 'i'))` statement which would be better. But aside from that your mistakes are: You need to get the string from the response. You are getting the response object. That is done like this: `response.getResponseText()`. Second you need to set the color of a range, not of the data itself. You can see how I updated both of these things below.

```
function HighlightMyTablet() {
  // Scan data in sheet. 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var row = ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  // Prompt user for input. 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('What\'s the tablet of the month?', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Iterate through rows. If data matches input then highlight yellow.
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    for (i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
      if(values[i][0] == response.getResponseText()) {
        ss.getRange('A'+ (i+1)).setBackground('red');
      }
    }  
  } 
}
```

Comment: Amazing! I wouldn't have thought to request the resonse's text.
Just one additional thing, how would I get the script to highlight the whole row corresponding to the users input? Rather than just the single cell?

Comment: ss.getRange('A' + (i+1) + ":Z" + (i+1)).setBackground('red'); Something like this.. This will highlight the first 26 rows, ZZ the first 52 etc. You should be able to do getRange(R,C,numR,numCol) as well, but I keep getting an error when I try. Not sure why.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: It would be my pleasure :)